# remove a lockscreen pin via adb with sqlite3

Tags: android, sqlite, locking, adb

Here is the original post I saw

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1409304

first I typed in :

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

However, in spite of what he stated, sqlite>in command prompt doesn't appear.

Instead, I get

> /system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found

how do i set sqlite working?

I'm unable to launch sqlite3 from adb shell

I can manually launch sqlite from the folder but not in cmd

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot into Recovery? If so, inside Recovery, enter the "Mounts and Storage Menu" and make sure everything is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install sqlite3 for root
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ptSoft.util.sqlite3forroot&hl=en